# Uncaught ReferenceError: h1Headers is not defined

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JQuery, I'm try to implement  basic jquery code but it's not working. Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  manipulateDOM();
});

function manipulateDOM() {
  var h1Headers = $('h1');
  var h3Headers = $('h3');
}

h1Headers.text('Hello World');
h3Headers.first().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
h3Headers.css('color', '#37887D');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
My HTML code:


<h1>H1 Header</h1>
<hr />
<h3>H3 Header</h3>
<hr />
<h3>Another H3 Header</h3>
```

Comment: Open your browser's Console (`F12`, `CMD+OPT+I`, etc) and see if there's any errors. If there are, edit them into your question.

Comment: You are defining h1Headers inside a function and then trying to use it outside the function. That is a problem with scope.

Comment: If you don't want to use a function, you could always do this: https://jsfiddle.net/m4ekx5we/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not useful code but the problem you are experiencing has to do with scope. The variables were created inside the function `manipulateDOM()` but then you are accessing them outside of the function. This is not allowed. You may create the variable outside the function and then use them inside the function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    manipulateDOM();
});

var h1Headers;
var h3Headers;

function manipulateDOM() {
    h1Headers = $('h1');
    h3Headers = $('h3');
}

h1Headers.text('Hello World');
h3Headers.first().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
h3Headers.css('color', '#37887D');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanielGale/Lz4eaq6f/)

Scope is a basic javascript and general programming concept and this problem is not related to the way JQuery works.

Javascript uses local and global variables. [W3Schools Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Alternatively you could place the variables and their use inside the `manipulateDOM()` function. You could remove the function completely and have everything done in the `ready()`, but since you're learning, what's the fun in that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    manipulateDOM();
});

function manipulateDOM() {
    //h1Headers and h3Headers are defined in function and disappear
    // after the function completes. The DOM is changed and those
    // changes will persist even though the variables no longer exist.
    var h1Headers = $('h1');
    var h3Headers = $('h3');

    h1Headers.text('Hello World');
    h3Headers.first().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    h3Headers.css('color', '#37887D');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the closing bracket of your `manipulateDOM()` function to include the action you want to take.

The variables `h1Headers` and `h3Headers` are created inside that function, and only last as long as it does. In your current code, they no longer exist when you try to use them to change the text and CSS, because those lines are outside of any function. This is why the variable is "undefined" in the error message. Look into "[variable scope](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)" in JavaScript.

```
function manipulateDOM() {
    var h1Headers = $('h1');
    var h3Headers = $('h3');

    h1Headers.text('Hello World');
    h3Headers.first().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    h3Headers.css('color', '#37887D');

}
```